# How do I delete defined rows in Google Sheets automatically everyday at midnight?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

No idea how to script this myself and googling hasn't helped.

What I want to do:

Delete columns E:H every day at midnight. That's it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-periodically-run-a-Google-Script-on-a-Spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

The first function creates a timebased trigger.

```
function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteEtoH').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
}
```

This function deletes columns 5 through 8

```
function deleteEtoH() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  sh.deleteColumns(5,4)                          
}
```

[Time Driven Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)